# flutter_app_badger with one_signal notification

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, onesignal

**I am using flutter_app_badger with one_signal when notification trigger the badge is not appearing on launcher icon. Here is my code sample. I call *FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(1);* like that but it is not working**

```
Future<void> configOneSignal() async {
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      await OneSignal.shared.init('');
      OneSignal.shared.setInFocusDisplayType(
        OSNotificationDisplayType.notification,
      );
      await OneSignal.shared.promptUserForPushNotificationPermission(
        fallbackToSettings: true,
      );

      OneSignal.shared.setNotificationReceivedHandler((notification) async {
        print(notification.jsonRepresentation().replaceAll('\\n', '\n'));
        FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(1);
      });

      OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler((openedResult) {
        print('Notification Opened');
        FlutterAppBadger.removeBadge();
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('OneSignal Exception : ${e.toString()}');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the phone model(s) you are using for testing this?

Comment: Vivo 1901 android 11

Comment: Most likely this is the problem. because Android does not support notification badge by default, every company has its own implementation for notification badge, so the library have to add the support for every company speratly. For example check out this library https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the ithe problem is the device model that your using. because Android does not support notification badge by default, every company has its own implementation for notification badge, so the library have to add the support for every company speratly. For example check out this [library](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger)

Comment: Ok I'll test on other devices Thank You

Comment: But the badge of other apps e.g. whatsapp Facebook etc working correctly fine on this device

Comment: these apps do not use OneSignal, they try to support every device manually. you can support Vivo devices by yourself but it will involve native android code and reading Vivo documentation. try a common device Like A Samsung device, most likely it will work.

Comment: Any sample code snippet to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately No. This question should be directed to vivo support team!